# Cython doesn't determine memoryview dimension change in sliced argument

Tags: python, cython, cythonize

I'm working with memoryviews of a fused type in a Cython application and have run into an issue where I expect Cython to know that a sliced 2D memoryview is a 1D memoryview, but can only get it to compile in 1 of 3 different ways.

```py
# cython: language_level=3, boundscheck=False, cdivision=True, wraparound=False, initializedcheck=False, nonecheck=False
cimport cython


cdef void _subfunc(cython.floating[:] arr1, cython.floating[:] out1, cython.floating[:] out2):
    out1[0] = arr1[0] ** 2
    out2[0] = arr1[0] + 2


cdef void _func1(cython.floating[:] arr1, cython.floating[:, ::1] out1):
    _subfunc(arr1, out1[:, 0], out1[:, 1])


cdef void _func2(cython.floating[:] arr1, cython.floating[:, ::1] out1):
    _subfunc(arr1, <cython.floating[:]>out1[:, 0], <cython.floating[:]>out1[:, 1])


cdef void _func3(cython.floating[:] arr1, cython.floating[:, ::1] out1):
    cdef cython.floating[:] o1, o2
    o1 = out1[:, 0]
    o2 = out1[:, 1]
    _subfunc(arr1, o1, o2)
```

When compiled with `cythonize test.pyx` I get the following errors:

```
Error compiling Cython file:
------------------------------------------------------------
...
cdef void _subfunc(cython.floating[:] arr1, cython.floating[:] out1, cython.floating[:] out2):
    out1[0] = arr1[0] ** 2
    out2[0] = arr1[0] + 2

cdef void _func1(cython.floating[:] arr1, cython.floating[:, ::1] out1):
    _subfunc(arr1, out1[:, 0], out1[:, 1])
            ^
------------------------------------------------------------

test.pyx:10:12: no suitable method found

Error compiling Cython file:
------------------------------------------------------------
...
cdef void _subfunc(cython.floating[:] arr1, cython.floating[:] out1, cython.floating[:] out2):
    out1[0] = arr1[0] ** 2
    out2[0] = arr1[0] + 2

cdef void _func1(cython.floating[:] arr1, cython.floating[:, ::1] out1):
    _subfunc(arr1, out1[:, 0], out1[:, 1])
            ^
------------------------------------------------------------

test.pyx:10:12: no suitable method found

Error compiling Cython file:
------------------------------------------------------------
...

cdef void _func1(cython.floating[:] arr1, cython.floating[:, ::1] out1):
    _subfunc(arr1, out1[:, 0], out1[:, 1])

cdef void _func2(cython.floating[:] arr1, cython.floating[:, ::1] out1):
    _subfunc(arr1, <cython.floating[:]>out1[:, 0], <cython.floating[:]>out1[:, 1])
                                           ^
------------------------------------------------------------

test.pyx:13:43: Can only create cython.array from pointer or array

Error compiling Cython file:
------------------------------------------------------------
...

cdef void _func1(cython.floating[:] arr1, cython.floating[:, ::1] out1):
    _subfunc(arr1, out1[:, 0], out1[:, 1])

cdef void _func2(cython.floating[:] arr1, cython.floating[:, ::1] out1):
    _subfunc(arr1, <cython.floating[:]>out1[:, 0], <cython.floating[:]>out1[:, 1])
                                                                           ^
------------------------------------------------------------

test.pyx:13:75: Can only create cython.array from pointer or array

Error compiling Cython file:
------------------------------------------------------------
...

cdef void _func1(cython.floating[:] arr1, cython.floating[:, ::1] out1):
    _subfunc(arr1, out1[:, 0], out1[:, 1])

cdef void _func2(cython.floating[:] arr1, cython.floating[:, ::1] out1):
    _subfunc(arr1, <cython.floating[:]>out1[:, 0], <cython.floating[:]>out1[:, 1])
                                           ^
------------------------------------------------------------

test.pyx:13:43: Can only create cython.array from pointer or array

Error compiling Cython file:
------------------------------------------------------------
...

cdef void _func1(cython.floating[:] arr1, cython.floating[:, ::1] out1):
    _subfunc(arr1, out1[:, 0], out1[:, 1])

cdef void _func2(cython.floating[:] arr1, cython.floating[:, ::1] out1):
    _subfunc(arr1, <cython.floating[:]>out1[:, 0], <cython.floating[:]>out1[:, 1])
                                                                           ^
------------------------------------------------------------

test.pyx:13:75: Can only create cython.array from pointer or array

Error compiling Cython file:
------------------------------------------------------------
...
cdef void _subfunc(cython.floating[:] arr1, cython.floating[:] out1, cython.floating[:] out2):
    out1[0] = arr1[0] ** 2
    out2[0] = arr1[0] + 2

cdef void _func1(cython.floating[:] arr1, cython.floating[:, ::1] out1):
    _subfunc(arr1, out1[:, 0], out1[:, 1])
    ^
------------------------------------------------------------

test.pyx:10:4: Invalid use of fused types, type cannot be specialized

Error compiling Cython file:
------------------------------------------------------------
...
cdef void _subfunc(cython.floating[:] arr1, cython.floating[:] out1, cython.floating[:] out2):
    out1[0] = arr1[0] ** 2
    out2[0] = arr1[0] + 2

cdef void _func1(cython.floating[:] arr1, cython.floating[:, ::1] out1):
    _subfunc(arr1, out1[:, 0], out1[:, 1])
    ^
------------------------------------------------------------

test.pyx:10:4: Invalid use of fused types, type cannot be specialized
```

As you can see, only `func3` with its explicit variables "o1" and "o2" satisfy the compilation. This is unexpected but also annoying since it is a lot more code. Is this just the way this has to be? Or am I doing something wrong?

Edit: It fails with the same errors with Cython 0.29.x and Cython 3.x.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Explicitly specifying `cython.floating` in the `_subfunc` call makes `_func1` compiling. Have no idea why, I just give it a try and it works, hope some expert could add the internal mechanisms.

```
cdef void _func1(cython.floating[:] arr1, cython.floating[:, ::1] out1):
    _subfunc[cython.floating](arr1, out1[:, 0], out1[:, 1])
```

https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/fusedtypes.html#selecting-specializations

Oh, **cython-3.0.0b3** is used.

Comment: Wow...that works. Even when I do `print(cython.typeof(out1[:, 0]))` it gives the right 1D memoryview type. Not sure why it couldn't figure this out automatically. I guess forcing the specialization is the way to go. I'm not sure if this would be considered a bug in cython.

Comment: File it as a bug anyway. It's possible there's a good reason why it isn't finding the specialization, but it kind of seems like it should. If it turns out not to be a bug then no harm done